# Erro ao receber array do php em ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

tenho um script como seguinte código:

```js
$("#submit").click(function(){

       var dataString ={
  nome : $("#nome").val(),
  status : $("#status").val(),
  id : $("#id").val()
    };
                   
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../vendors/php/ins_salvar_menu.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache : false,
            success: function(data){
     console.log(data.nome);
     console.log(data);
              if(data.type == 'add'){
                 $("#menu-id").append(data.menu);
              } else if(data.type == 'edit'){
                 $('#nome_show'+data.id).html(data.nome);
                 $('#status_show'+data.id).html(data.status);
              }
              $('#nome').val('');
              $('#status').val('');
              $('#id').val('');
     

            } ,error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              alert(error);
            },
        });
    });
```

> Que envia os dados para uma pagina PHP cuja seu conteúdo é o seguinte:

```html
<?php 
include "../../seguranca/banco/conexao_banco.php";
include "operacaobd_php.php";
date_default_timezone_set ("America/Sao_Paulo");
$data_criacao = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
$data_modificacao = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
if($_POST['id'] != ''){
 $tabela="categorias";
 $dados = array(
  'nome' => $_POST['nome'],
  'status' => $_POST['status'],
  'data_modificacao'=> $data_modificacao
 ); 
 $condicao = array(
  'id' => $_POST['id']
 );
 $sql_upd_categorias_resultado = alterar($tabela, $condicao, $dados);
 
 
 $arr['type']  = 'edit';
 $arr['nome'] = $_POST['nome'];
 $arr['status']  = $_POST['status'];
 $arr['id']    = $_POST['id'];
}else{
 $tabela="categorias";
 $dados = array(
  'nome' => $_POST['nome'],
  'status' => $_POST['status'],
  'data_criacao'=> $data_criacao,
  'data_modificacao'=> $data_modificacao
 );
 $sql_ins_categorias_resultado = adicionar($tabela, $dados);

 $arr['type'] = 'add';
 $arr['menu'] = '<li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="'.$conexaobd->lastInsertId().'" >
                    <div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">Drag</div>
                    <div class="dd3-content"><span id="nome_show'.$conexaobd->lastInsertId().'">'.$_POST['nome'].'</span> 
                        <span class="span-right">/<span id="status_show'.$conexaobd->lastInsertId().'">'.$_POST['status'].'</span> &nbsp;&nbsp; 
                            <a class="edit-button" id="'.$conexaobd->lastInsertId().'" nome="'.$_POST['nome'].'" status="'.$_POST['status'].'" ><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                            <a class="del-button" id="'.$conexaobd->lastInsertId().'"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></span> 
                    </div>';
}
return json_encode($arr);

?>
```

**A função adicionar:**

```
function adicionar($adc_tabela, $adc_dados){

// Armazenas os dados do array
$adc_campos = array_keys($adc_dados);
print_r($adc_campos);
// contagem dos campos existentes
$adc_n_campos = count($adc_dados);
// Inicia a sintaxe
$adc_sintaxe = "INSERT INTO ".$adc_tabela." (";
//monta o resto da estrutura
for($adc_aux=0; $adc_aux<$adc_n_campos; $adc_aux++){
    $adc_sintaxe.= $adc_campos[$adc_aux].", ";
}
//retira a ultima virgula
$adc_sintaxe = substr($adc_sintaxe, 0, -2);
// fecha os campos e adciona o VALUES na sintaxe
$adc_sintaxe .= ") VALUES (";
//adiciona os valores na sintaxe
for($adc_aux=0; $adc_aux<$adc_n_campos; $adc_aux++){
    $adc_sintaxe.= ":".$adc_campos[$adc_aux].", ";
}
// Retira a ultima virgula
$adc_sintaxe = substr($adc_sintaxe, 0, -2);
// Fim da sintaxe
$adc_sintaxe .= ")";
// chama a função global para fazer conexão com o Banco de dados
global $conexaobd;
// prepara a sintaxe
$adc_preparado = $conexaobd->prepare($adc_sintaxe);
// seta os valores de cada campo
for($adc_aux=0; $adc_aux<$adc_n_campos; $adc_aux++){
    /*if((!$adc_dados[$adc_campos[$adc_aux]]) AND (!$adc_dados[$adc_campos[$adc_aux]]=="0")){
        $adc_dados[$adc_campos[$adc_aux]] = NULL;
    }
    OBS.: o IF acima buga com o 0, então se algum dos dados for ==0 ele atribui NULL, então o IF acima corrige o problema com o 0
    */
    if(!$adc_dados[$adc_campos[$adc_aux]]){
        if($adc_dados[$adc_campos[$adc_aux]] == "0" ){
            $adc_dados[$adc_campos[$adc_aux]] = 0;
        }else{
            $adc_dados[$adc_campos[$adc_aux]] = NULL;
        }
    }
    $adc_preparado -> BindValue(":".$adc_campos[$adc_aux], $adc_dados[$adc_campos[$adc_aux]]);
    /*
     print_r($adc_dados[$adc_campos[$adc_aux]]);
     echo"<br>";
    */
}
  return $adc_preparado->execute();
}
```

> O problema em sí:

No arquivo JS ele manda para esta pagina PHP, e retorna os dados. onde ele verifica se `data.type=="add"` ou se é `data.type="edit"`, infelizmente ao dar um `console.log(data.type)` a mensagem é undefined, e um `console.log(data)` retorna um array que não devia estar retornando, que no caso é:

```
Array(
    [0] => nome
    [1] => status
    [2] => data_criacao
    [3] => data_modificacao
)
```

qual seria o erro?

Comment: @13dev de onde saiu esse método que você adicionou na pergunta? Esse tipo de edição deve ser evitada, ainda mais que o autor não cita nada desse trecho nem em posts deletados. Sempre opte por orientar que o proprio autor edite a pergunta.

Comment: @Articuno entendido, erro meu, este método é do próprio autor, onde na resposta que fiz pedi esse mesmo método, mas ao pedir disse ao autor para editar a resposta ( enganei-me ao pedir, queria dizer pergunta ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui tens o código com algumas alterações e melhores hábitos para a tua programação.

Para ser direto teu código está mau, aqui vai a possível solução que seria usares a função **[isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)**:

tem em atenção os comentários que deixei

```
<?php 
include "../../seguranca/banco/conexao_banco.php";
include "operacaobd_php.php";

date_default_timezone_set ("America/Sao_Paulo");
$data_criacao = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
$data_modificacao = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
$tabela = "categorias";

// começa sempre a verificar pela negatividade
// ou seja nega sempre a condição só no final é que retornas o pretendido
// usa função isset para verificares se a variável existe
if(!isset($_POST['id'])){

    $dados = array(
        'nome' => $_POST['nome'],
        'status' => $_POST['status'],
        'data_criacao'=> $data_criacao,
        'data_modificacao'=> $data_modificacao
    );

    $sql_ins_categorias_resultado = adicionar($tabela, $dados);

    $arr['type'] = 'add';

    // nunca deves retornar html em ajax é má pratica!
    // tenta retornar so um array com os dados necessários
    // e com jquery ou js tratas os dados retornados pela requisição ajax
    $arr['menu'] = '<li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="'.$conexaobd->lastInsertId().'" >
                    <div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">Drag</div>
                    <div class="dd3-content"><span id="nome_show'.$conexaobd->lastInsertId().'">'.$_POST['nome'].'</span> 
                        <span class="span-right">/<span id="status_show'.$conexaobd->lastInsertId().'">'.$_POST['status'].'</span> &nbsp;&nbsp; 
                            <a class="edit-button" id="'.$conexaobd->lastInsertId().'" nome="'.$_POST['nome'].'" status="'.$_POST['status'].'" ><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                            <a class="del-button" id="'.$conexaobd->lastInsertId().'"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></span> 
                    </div>';

    return json_encode($arr);

}
// se o id esta definido
// verifica se os dados neste caso o POST EXISTE não podes confiar no utilizador
$dados = array(
    'nome' => $_POST['nome'],
    'status' => $_POST['status'],
    'data_modificacao'=> $data_modificacao
);  

//porque guardas o retorno se não esta a usa-lo (codigo apresentado na resposta)
//variavel com nome tão grande!
$sql_upd_categorias_resultado = alterar($tabela,  array( 'id' => $_POST['id'] ), $dados);

$arr['type']    = 'edit';

// verifica se os dados existem, não deves confiar no utilizador
$arr['nome']    = (isset($_POST['nome'])) ? $_POST['nome']  : '';
$arr['status']  = (isset($_POST['status'])) ? $_POST['status'] : '';
$arr['id']      = (isset($_POST['id']) && is_numeric($_POST['id'])) ? $_POST['id']  : null;

return json_encode($arr);

?>
```

**EDIT:**
Aqui esta o código com os defeitos que apontei corrigidos,

antes de tudo se tiveres interesse entra neste [site](http://www.phptherightway.com/)
que te dará boas maneiras de programar em **PHP**.

```
<?php 
// minha opiniao: funções que alteram configuração do php eu meto sempre no topo
date_default_timezone_set ("America/Sao_Paulo");

// se possivel usa ingles em nomes de ficheiros exemplo: ConnectDB.php
include "../../seguranca/banco/conexao_banco.php"; // sugestão: muda para OpenDatabase.php ou ConnectDB.php
include ("operacaobd_php.php"); // sugestão muda o nome do arquivo pois não é claro ex: OperationsDatabase.php


// tenta usar nome de variaveis em ingles
// assim todos que verem teu codigo saberá do que se trata
$createData = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
$modificationData = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
$table = "categorias";

//verifica se os indices do $_POST existe
$postName = (isset($_POST['nome'])) ? filter_var($_POST['nome'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : NULL;
$postStatus = (isset($_POST['status'])) ? filter_var($_POST['status'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : NULL;
$postID = (isset($_POST['id']) && is_numeric($_POST['id'])) ? $_POST['id'] : NULL;

// fiz tudo de uma vez mas faz separadamente
if(is_null($postName) || is_null($postStatus))
{
    return json_decode(['error' => 'algumas das variveis post não estao definidas']);
}

if($postID === NULL){

    $dados = [
        'nome' => $postName,
        'status' => $postStatus,
        'data_criacao'=> $createData,
        'data_modificacao'=> $modificationData,
        'type' => 'add'
    ];


    if(!adicionar($tabela, $dados)){
        return json_encode(['error' => 'Erro ao adicionar a base de dados por favor tente novamente']);
    }

    //$arr['menu'] = '<li class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="'.$conexaobd->lastInsertId().'" ><div class="dd-handle dd3-handle">Drag</div><div class="dd3-content"><span id="nome_show'.$conexaobd->lastInsertId().'">'.$_POST['nome'].'</span> <span class="span-right">/<span id="status_show'.$conexaobd->lastInsertId().'">'.$_POST['status'].'</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;  <a class="edit-button" id="'.$conexaobd->lastInsertId().'" nome="'.$_POST['nome'].'" status="'.$_POST['status'].'" ><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a><a class="del-button" id="'.$conexaobd->lastInsertId().'"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></span> </div>';

    // aqui adiciona os valores que estavas juntando ao HTML
    // no array acima ($arr['menu']) como exemplo ['data-id' => $conexaobd->lastInsertId()]
    return json_encode(['type' => 'add', 'error' => null]);

}

$dados = [
    'nome' => $postName,
    'status' => $postStatus,
    'data_modificacao'=> $modificationData
];  


if(!alterar($table, [ 'id' => $postID ], $dados)){
    return json_encode(['error' => 'Erro ao alterar na base de dados por favor tente novamente!']);
}

return json_encode([
        'type' => 'edit',
        'nome' => $postName,
        'status' => $postStatus,
        'id' => $postID,
        'error' => null
]);
```

Comment: posto isto, se quiseres o script 'corrigido' pelos erros que mencionei é só dizeres para alterar a resposta

Comment: obrigado, realmente concordo com sua correção na verdade esse código não é totalmente meu, ele é de um exemplo pego na internet, algumas coisas ai  como função de insert e update são minhas. mas obrigado pela critica construtiva. Se poderes também postar o código corrigido me ajudará muito!

Comment: sim e resolveu o teu problema este codigo ? uns minutos e ja posto o codigo com os defeitos que apontei

Comment: resolveu, sim, na verdade ele é maior que isso, oq postei é uma parte do código do  plugin nestable.

Comment: resposta editada com o script em 'condições'

Comment: Obrigado, ficou show. mas quando dou um console.log(data.type); ele continua me retornando undefined. :C

Comment: faz `console.log(data); ` e mostra o que retornou

Comment: retorna isso:
`Array
(
    [0] => nome
    [1] => status
    [2] => data_criacao
    [3] => data_modificacao
)`

Comment: o correto não seria ele retornar oq esta dentro do json_encode?

Comment: edita a resposta e coloca o código desta função: `adicionar()`, sim seria o correto, mas ele não esta a chegar ate esse return por isso o erro pode estar nessa função

Comment: Adicionado, é uma função que uso em todo o site, tenho ela que é INSERT, tenho a  UPDATE e DELETE

Comment: pois é estas a fazer um `print_r($adc_campos)` dentro da função **adicionar** por isso é que esta a te retornar php e não json!

Comment: retira todo o codigo debug(print_r, var_dump, etc) e testa lá a aplicação

Comment: Então retirei, e nada, ta retornando vazio agora. Só para verificar existe um else do $postID === NULL ?

Comment: Tenta fazer debug linha por linha no arquivo, não porque dentro dessa mesma condição tem um return, o que quer dizer que vai parar ali o script

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, to tentando faz tempo aqui, vou ficar tentando se consigo achar esse erro....

Comment: 13, testei tudo, só consegui trocando o `return` pelo `print`, e agr ele ta recebendo, adicionei tbm no script o `data=JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: agora que adicionaste `data=JSON.parse(data);` tenta usar o return invés do print

Comment: aparece o seguinte: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (menu.js:55)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at z (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)`

Comment: verifica se o que vem do arquivo php e esta convertido para json

Answer (score -1):

Em chamadas $.ajax(); do jQuery, quando você recebe um json você pode especificar o parâmetro dataType: "json".

O data recebido por success: function(data){} será convertido para objeto,
se a resposta não for um json válido, vai cair em error: function(xhr, status, error){}
para ser tratado pela sua aplicação.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../vendors/php/ins_salvar_menu.php",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "json",
    cache : false,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data.nome);
        console.log(data);
        if(data.type == 'add'){
            $("#menu-id").append(data.menu);
        } else if(data.type == 'edit'){
            $('#nome_show'+data.id).html(data.nome);
            $('#status_show'+data.id).html(data.status);
        }
        $('#nome').val('');
        $('#status').val('');
        $('#id').val('');


    } ,error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    },
});
```

Comment: Não entendi porque negativaram a minha resposta, apenas dei uma dica para evitar o uso do data=JSON.parse(data); implementando um dataType: "json"